# Problems with list and dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello stackoverflow community. I need help with my list. I need to make something like this:[image]

[image]
As you can see, on button press, list with checkbox'es drops down. How can i make that drop down full width like in the picture? So long I made this something similar but cant figure it out, how to make full width, so that other buttons would move down. Here is my code in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/13790/

So to be sure I need that my ul > a would be the same size as it is but ul > li would be full width and push other buttons down.
Html:

```
<div class="categ-list">
    <ul class="col-md-4 parent">
        <a href="#">Menu link</a>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Menu link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Menu link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Menu link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="col-md-4 parent">
        <a href="#">Menu link</a>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Menu link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Menu link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Menu link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="col-md-4 parent">
        <a href="#">Menu link</a>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Menu link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Menu link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Menu link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="col-md-4 parent">
        <a href="#">Menu link</a>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Menu link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Menu link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Menu link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="col-md-4 parent">
        <a href="#">Menu link</a>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Menu link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Menu link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Menu link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="col-md-4 parent">
        <a href="#">Menu link</a>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Menu link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Menu link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Menu link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.categ-list {    
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.categ-list > ul {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
.categ-list > ul > a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    background: #1e7c9a;
    margin-left: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.categ-list > ul > li > a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
    padding: 3px 15px;
    background: #344F57 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    margin-left: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.categ-list > ul > li > a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(93, 93, 93);
}
.kat-active {
    background: #3b3b3b!important;
}
.categ-list > ul > a:hover {
    background: #3b3b3b;
}
.categ-list > ul > a:hover {
    background: #3b3b3b;
}
.categ-list > ul:hover ul a:hover {
    background: #1e7c9a;
}
.displayNone {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/13792/

Comment: @odedta LOL. I need that my ul > a would be the same size as it is but ul > li would be full width and push other buttons down :) Nice try

Comment: Hehe, I honestly don't know what you're trying to do, could you create a sketch? from what I understand you have a nav menu where one of the items is a full width menu, and it pushes all the content below when it opens up, is that correct?

Comment: Can you create an image without scribbles all over it so we can actually see what is going on

Comment: Here is image http://s21.postimg.org/t0zyhvp13/wtfffff.jpg

Comment: @odedta updated my question

Comment: Are the buttons below the green box also navigation elements? Is it responsive?

Comment: Ye you can see that in my jsfiddle